# Query para listar quantidade de ocorrências

Tags: sql

Estou tentando listar a quantidade de CATEGORIAS que cada PESSOA tem mas somente quero retornar se a PESSOA tiver mais de uma CATEGORIA. Minha query está assim e não retorna nada. E eu sei que tem casos pra se mostrar.

```
SELECT COUNT(*), PESSOA_FK,CATEGORIA_IDENTIFICACAO_FK FROM IDENTIFICACAO_PESSOA
GROUP BY PESSOA_FK,CATEGORIA_IDENTIFICACAO_FK
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;
```

Comment: Está acontecendo alguma pegadinha que não estou conseguindo identificar. Se eu usar só PESSOA_FK ele traz muitos registros mas eu preciso saber a quantidade de CATEGORIA que cada pessoa tem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Da forma que está a *query* só retornará se a pessoa tiver mais de uma vez a mesma categoria. Para listar a quantidade de categorias por pessoa, você precisa não agrupar por categoria:

```
SELECT COUNT(*), PESSOA_FK 
FROM IDENTIFICACAO_PESSOA 
WHERE PESSOA_FK IN (SELECT PESSOA_FK FROM IDENTIFICACAO_PESSOA WHERE CATEGORIA_IDENTIFICACAO_FK = 10) --ou qualquer outra validação
GROUP BY PESSOA_FK 
HAVING COUNT() > 1
```

obs: esta consulta é considerando que a categoria seja obrigatória; sendo assim, cada ocorrência na tabela `IDENTIFICACAO_PESSOA` terá uma pessoa e uma categoria.

Comment: Sabe me dizer o porque quando eu especifico CATEGORIA no where ele não traz nada ? Assim o seu realmente funcionou.

Comment: quando você agrupa (`group by`) por mais de um campo, ele só contará se todos forem iguais; ou seja, se a pessoa `joão` tiver duas categorias, `alto` e `novo`, sua consulta retornaria total 1 para "joão alto" e total 1 para "joão novo", o que não é o que você quer. Agrupando apenas por nome, ele trará total 2 para "joão" (1 pra "alto" e 1 pra "novo")

Comment: Achei, era um nó cego meu.Vou validar a sua resposta mas só edite ela pra ficar assim: SELECT COUNT(*), PESSOA_FK
FROM IDENTIFICACAO_PESSOA
WHERE PESSOA_FK IN (SELECT PESSOA_FK FROM IDENTIFICACAO_PESSOA WHERE CATEGORIA_IDENTIFICACAO_FK = 10)
GROUP BY PESSOA_FK
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1

Comment: até posso editar mas não sei se a alteração tem relação com a pergunta; se entendi é uma condição que você até então não precisava :P

Comment: eu posso ter me expressado errado na pergunta ou não ficou claro rsrs. Mas isso aí é meu objetivo :) De toda forma muito obrigado.

Answer (score 1):

Assumindo uma estrutura similar a sua:

```
CREATE TABLE IDENTIFICACAO_PESSOA
(
    PESSOA_FK BIGINT,
    CATEGORIA_IDENTIFICACAO_FK character varying(1)
);
```

Com os seguintes dados de teste:

```
INSERT INTO IDENTIFICACAO_PESSOA ( PESSOA_FK, CATEGORIA_IDENTIFICACAO_FK ) VALUES ( 1 , 'B' );
INSERT INTO IDENTIFICACAO_PESSOA ( PESSOA_FK, CATEGORIA_IDENTIFICACAO_FK ) VALUES ( 2 , 'A' );
INSERT INTO IDENTIFICACAO_PESSOA ( PESSOA_FK, CATEGORIA_IDENTIFICACAO_FK ) VALUES ( 2 , 'B' );
INSERT INTO IDENTIFICACAO_PESSOA ( PESSOA_FK, CATEGORIA_IDENTIFICACAO_FK ) VALUES ( 2 , 'C' );
INSERT INTO IDENTIFICACAO_PESSOA ( PESSOA_FK, CATEGORIA_IDENTIFICACAO_FK ) VALUES ( 3 , 'X' );
INSERT INTO IDENTIFICACAO_PESSOA ( PESSOA_FK, CATEGORIA_IDENTIFICACAO_FK ) VALUES ( 4 , 'Y' );
```

A sua query ficaria assim:

```
SELECT
    DISTINCT
        PESSOA_FK AS id_pessoa,
        COUNT(1) AS qtd_categorias
FROM
    IDENTIFICACAO_PESSOA
GROUP BY
    PESSOA_FK
HAVING
    COUNT(1) > 1;
```

SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/22a21/1/0